# Explanation of differentiating implicit functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

$F(x,y,z)=0$, where $F \in C^2$ in some neighborhood of point (a,b,c) in which $F(a,b,c)\neq 0$ For the constant function $(x,y)->F(x,y,f(x,y))$ based on $f'(x,y)=-(D_zF(x,y,z))^{-1}(D_xF(x,y,z),D_yF(x,y,z))$ we have $f_{x}={-{F_{x}\over F_{z}}}$ and $f_{y}={-{F_{y}\over F_{z}}}$ where these indexes indicate partial derivatives. I don't understand how this last conclusion is derived.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? The last conclusion? You mean how $f_{x}={-{F_{x}\over F_{z}}}$ and  $f_{y}={-{F_{y}\over F_{z}}}$ follow from what comes before?

Comment: I honestly don't understand why, could you explain?

Comment: Explain what? I still don't know what you don't understand.

Comment: I dont understand how after  $f'(x,y)=-(D_zF(x,y,z))^{-1}(D_xF(x,y,z),D_yF(x,y,z))$ the conclusion  $f_{x}={-{F_{x}\over F_{z}}}$ and $f_{y}={-{F_{y}\over F_{z}}}$ is drawn.

Comment: Just write $f'(x,y)$ explicitly. Do you know what it is?

Comment: Unfortunately i do not but have tried $f'(x,y)=f_{x}dx+f_{y}dy$,$f_{x}dx+f_{y}dy=-(D_zF(x,y,z))^{-1}(D_xF(x,y,z),D_yF(x,y,z))$ multiplied both sides by $D_zF(x,y,z)$ and get i feel like i can't any furthur i assume ive made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: The notation $f'(x,y)$ is the differential of $f$ at $(x,y)$. Since $f$ is a scalar function, this is just the gradient evaluated at $(x,y)$, that is, $f'(x,y)=\left(f_x(x,y), f_y(x,y)\right)$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, for reminding me, very useful and discrete, which i did not see! :D

Comment: No worries. If no one answers the question in a couple of days, I suggest you either delete it or answer it yourself.